# Angular UI Bootstrap modal display during $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am trying to create a directive that uses angular ui bootstrap modal. I would like to open this directive from my controller when a $http request is made, and close it when the request resolves. I'm new to angular and a bit stuck. Here's what I've got so far.

expedition.html controller:

```
.controller('ExpeditionCtrl', ['$http', 'UserFactory', '$scope',
    function ($http, UserFactory, $scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.totalItems;
        vm.itemsPerPage = 100;
        vm.currentPage = 1;
        vm.pageChanged = pageChanged;
        vm.content = [];
        vm.loadingInstance;
        vm.open;
        fetchPage();

        function pageChanged() {
            fetchPage();
        }

        function fetchPage() {

            $http.get('myapi?page=' + vm.currentPage + "&limit=" + vm.itemsPerPage)
                .then(function(response) {
                    angular.extend(vm.content, response.data.content);
                    vm.content = response.data.content;
                    vm.totalItems = response.data.totalElements;
                })
        }

    }
```

expedition.html:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="sectioncontent">
        // some html

            <uib-pagination total-items="vm.totalItems" ng-model="vm.currentPage" ng-change="vm.pageChanged()" items-per-page="vm.itemsPerPage"></uib-pagination>

        </div>
        <loading-modal loadingInstance="vm.loadingInstance" open="vm.open"></loading-modal>
    </div>
</div>
```

loadingModal.directive.js:

```
.directive('loadingModal', ['$uibModal',
    function($modal) {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'EA',
            template: '<div ng-init="open()"> Test Loading </div>',
            scope: {
                loadingInstance: "=",
                open: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                scope.open = function(){

                    scope.loadingInstance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'app/templates/loadingModal.tpl.html',
                        controller:  scope.useCtrl,
                        size: 'sm',
                        windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
                        backdrop: true,

                    });
                    scope.loadingInstance.result.then(function(){
                        scope.initialized = true;
                        console.log('Finished');
                    }, function(){
                        scope.initialized = true;
                        console.log('Modal dismissed at : ' + new Date());
                    });
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

loadingModal.tpl.html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    Loading ....
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the content of the module template in the question

Comment: You haven't included the part in which you call the `$uibModalInstance.close()` (Or `$uibModalInstance.dismiss()`), but you need to call one of those function after the request has been resolved.

Comment: right, I hadn't done that as I haven't been able to get the modal to open. I haven't been able to open the dialog. I tried using ng-init in the directive template. "template: '<div ng-init="open()"> Test Loading </div>'," Also, when I tried to manually open the modal, I got an error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=loadingInstance&p2=loadingModal

Comment: I think `ng-init` is messing this up. try to remove `ng-init` and move all of the `scope.open` function outside.

Comment: @MuliYulzary: If I remove ng-init, the modal will open on page load, however I still get an error about not being able to assign the modal instance to an undefined variable, so I can't close it from my controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to do this by using a factory. Then in the controller, I call LoadingModalFactory.open() when I initiate a $http request, and LoadingModalFactory.modalInstance.close() when the request resolves. Maybe there's a better way to do this, but for now this is working.

```
.factory('LoadingModalFactory', ['$uibModal', function($uibModal) {
    var modalInstance;
    var loadingModalFactory = {
        open: open,
        modalInstance: modalInstance,
    };

    return loadingModalFactory;

    function open() {
        loadingModalFactory.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/components/modals/templates/loadingModal.tpl.html',
            size: 'sm',
            windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
            backdrop: true,

        });
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `fetchPage()` function:

1. Open the modal and return its object to a variable
2. Run the $http call and in the resolution, close the modal with its stored variable reference

`var modal = $uibModal.open({
        //your modal config
    });
    $http.get(...).then(function(response) {
        modal.close();
    });`

I may be going outside of the question, but you don't *have* to do this in a directive.  You can still modularize this by using a template for the modal and a controller for the modal defined elsewhere.

If you need to do this in a directive, you could pass the http get function into the directive with the '&' scope property.

Comment: If I didn't use a directive, then I would need to type the modal config in every controller I want to use. Is passing the http get function the only way to make this a directive?